# Retrieving the type of a Collection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections

So I have something like the following in Java:

```
private List<SomeType>variable;

// ....variable is instantiated as so ...
variable = new ArrayList<SomeType>();

// there's also a getter
public List<SomeType> getVariable() { /* code */ }
```

What I would like to be able to do is figure out that `variable` is a collection of  `SomeType` programmatically. I read [here](http://i-proving.com/space/BC+Holmes/blog/2008-11-18_2) that I can determine that from the method `getVariable()` but is there any way to tell directly from `variable`?

I have been able to retrieve `SomeType` from the getter method based on the information in the link. I have also been successful in retrieving all the fields of the surrounding class via `SurroundingClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` but this doesn't tell me that it is `List<SomeType>`.

EDIT: Based on bmargulies's response doing the following will achieve what I want:

```
Field[] fields = SurroundingClass.getDeclaredFields();
/* assuming it is in fields[0] and is a ParameterizedType */
ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) fields[0].getGenericType(); 
Type[] types = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
/* from types I'm able to see the information I've been looking for */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get this from the instance, due to type erasure. At runtime, `XXX<T>` is really just `XXX`. Unless the class makes special arrangements to store a Class reference for the T, it's completely and totally gone.

You can get it from getDeclaredFields(). You have to call getGenericType on the Field, not getType, and then you have to do some casting to ParameterizedType and then ask it for the parameter you want.

Comment: Ahh, getDeclaredFields() turns out to work perfectly after casting it to ParameterizedType.

Answer (score 1):

You can get SomeType by looking at one of the elements in the Collection

```
Collection<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
for ( Object x : abc ) { String className = x.getClass().getName(); break; }
```

Comment: I thought about trying this but didn't because I don't have an actual object to work with and I didn't want to instantiate an instance of this object either. However, good to know this is a valid approach as well.